# cant point Hostinger custom domain to herokuapp

Tags: heroku, hosting, cname

I have deployed a django based app on heroku which works (https://removedapp.herokuapp.com)

I have a domain that i bought from hostinger (removeddomain.space)

Now i want to use my hostinger domain with herokuapp and I followed the process mentioned at heroku that I should point my DNS CNAME to server returned by heroku.
So I added cname records but it is still not working.

Please tell me how can I point my domain to this free herokuapp

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this tutorial:

https://www.mirrorcommunications.com/blog/how-to-correctly-point-your-domain-to-heroku

If you found another solution, could you put here?

I've created in Heroku two custom domains:

One with www `www.namesite.com` and another without www `namesite.com`.

After this, in **Hostinger > Domain > DNS ZONE** I **changed** in **CNAME** table the values **Point to** from the hosts `@` and `www` with the DNS heroku's 'DNS target' of **two created domains**.

Answer (score 2):

The A DNS Record requires an IP Address.

This represents your domain without 'www.' i.e. https://example.com

Heroku cannot provide an IP Address since it constantly changes.
They provide urls.

Which is perfect for CNAME Records.

CNAME represents your domain with the www. 'prefix'. i.e. 'https://www.example.com'

But it is an issue for A Records since an IP Address is required.

Meaning if you add the CNAME Record, 'https://www.example.com' will redirect to your Heroku app, but 'https://example.com' will not.

---

Newer services support CNAME flattening/ALIAS/ANAME.

CNAME flattening/ALIAS/ANAME is the equivalent of being able to add a URL to am A Record instead of an IP Address.

This fixes the issue since you can simply add your Heroku URL.

Hostinger, however, does not support CNAME flattening/ALIAS/ANAME yet.

---

Another solution is to use DNS Forwarding, but that is also not available on Hostinger unless you move to Clouflare

---

Hostinger has a "Redirect" section in cPanel but that didn’t work in redirecting 'https://example.com' to 'https://www.example.com' either.

---

A workaround for all these issues on Hostinger is to add an A Record in DNS Management that points to your Hostinger server IP Address.

In that server we create an .htcaccess file.

And in that file we add code for a permanent 301 redirect to your 'https://www.example.com' (i.e. your Heroku app).

Below is the code that should be added to your .htcaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The way to get the IP Address of Hostinger to point to that .htcaccess file is by checking the left panel inside the cPanel or going into Details section.

---

You can show this to your Hostinger support in the chat section and they can do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Jaad Chacra's answer.
It can be done on your own.
While you are logged in under the Hostinger hpanel, if you navigate under the website tab, select your website and the manage button, go to Files, File Manager, access files of example.com, within the public_html file select New file and name it .htaccess. (this is assuming you are only redirecting the custom domain to heroku so there hasn't been one created)  Then post Jaad Chacra's code and save.

Comment: Hi Lance, I tried but I need 50 reputation points to comment directly on another users comment.

Comment: Also just to note, a 301 redirect can also be done from the hpanel by choosing domains and then redirects.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. My setup is Django on Heroku. Domain name on Hostinger.

On Hostinger I did `Add Record` with this info:

```
Type: CNAME  <--- The moment I clicked 'Add Record', it changes state to ALIAS
Name: @
Priority: 0
Content: lama-unicorn-1984hello.herokudns.com
TTL: 300
```

I had to remove the default `A` record that pointed to hostingers static IP address.

Now the root domain (without www) points to my heroku server.